# How to download ticks from financial data sources (yfinance, Quandl, Intrinio , iexfinance, tiingo, alpha_vantage) and save it in csv format in Julia?

Tags: julia

It is understood from [Can't save data from yfinance into a CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56782173/cant-save-data-from-yfinance-into-a-csv-file), that ticks can be downloaded from yfinance and it can be saved in csv format using python.

Please guide me in achieving the same using Julia.

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried, what isn't working?

There currently isn't a working Julia package that wraps the Yahoo Finance API, so you can either write one yourself using `HTTP.jl` or use the Python library you linked via `PyCall.jl` or an R library (e.g. described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48568159/get-data-from-yahoo-finance-to-r)) via `RCall.jl`.

Once you have the data you can do `using CSV; CSV.write("/path/to/file.csv", downloaded_data)` to write it to csv.